# How to apply binary search in an array of object in java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have fetched the contents of a table in array of object. And the object is holding the columns of the table COUNTRYCODES into its own data members which names are , startingRange, endingRange and countryCode.

Actually the table is describing the country codes which is corresponding to the range of startingRange and endingRange of the table. Now I have stored this table in an array of object which name is countryCodes[]. I need to search the country code from the array by giving a range which could be between any range(i.e. between any startingRange and endingRange).

To do this I want to use binary search because I dont want to search the countrycode location by location. To minimize the searching efforts I want to use binary search.
Please help by guiding me.

Thank you.

Comment: What are countryCodes, startingRange, endingRange ? What are their datatypes?

Comment: Have you thought about using the db query to just retrieve those elements where the country code equals your search? By merging your query with your search that should make it more efficient perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but what you can do is:

Assuming that the array is *already sorted*, you could use the [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) mechanism to perform a binary search on your array.